# Count/frequency of observations by month

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with 34 variables and about 25,000 observations.  Each observation refers to a specific incident.  Its formatted something like this:

```
  no    id    date         ....
1 363   006   2005-11-05
2 939   012   2007-01-23
3 541   090   2009-06-14
```

I'm wondering if someone could walk me through how to get the total number of incidents for each month over the 5 years contained in this dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you just want to count the number of rows for each month, if so you can just use `table()`:

```
> #make junk data
> data <- data.frame(no=rnorm(100),id=rnorm(100),date=seq(Sys.Date()-99,Sys.Date(),by="day"))
> table(format(data$date,"%b-%Y"))
Aug-2013 Jul-2013 Nov-2013 Oct-2013 Sep-2013 
      31        7        1       31       30
```

Comment: Ah ok, this is a good start.  I need the month and year though. Sou totals for 1-2004, 2-2004, ... 1-2009, 2-2009.  And then store the totals as a variable (I can probably figure this out).

Comment: Didn't know you wanted to years too, I edited the solution for you.

Comment: Ok last question, any way to format it as a date, instead of a factor so that I can sort it by year, instead of alphabetically when I put it in a data frame?  Right now when I use as.date() I just get NAs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the end goal is (in the future it is help for you post an example of your desired end result), but I'm sure there many ways to get there. The simplist may just be re-formatting the day to a sort-friendly format in the first place, like: `table(format(data$date,"%Y%m"))`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.  thanks for the help, I ultimately got it.  I constantly have problems with as.Date() and getting NA values...

Answer (score 0):

```
tapply( dfrm$no, sub(".+-(.+)-.+", "\\1", dfrm$date), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

For month and year in MM-YYYY format use this as you category code:

```
.... , sub("(.+)-(.+)-.+", "\\2-\\1", data$date) , ....
```